# Understanding Latin abbreviations in Papers and the Such

Tags: abbreviations, latin, shorthand

Preface:

I have begun reading over some of the documents from the Vatican II council to familiarise myself with the material for when I talk with people that I know that are catholic, and I am having troubles understanding the footnotes.

Question examples:

The first footnote in the first constitution (Called "The Word of God") is as follows: ***cf. St. Augustine, "De Catechizandis Rudibus," C.IV 8: PL. 40, 316.***

I have deduced some of this as meaning: *confer to "De Catechizandis Rudibus,"* however, it is the rest that throws me for a loop. Primarily, ***PL.*** and I believe ***C.*** means *circa.*

THESE ARE SOME MORE EXAMPLES:

f. Council of Trent, session IV, loc. cit.: Denzinger 783 (1501).

cf. Second Council of Nicea: Denzinger 303 (602); Fourth Council of Constance, session X, Canon 1: Denzinger 336 (650-652).

Cf. Ibid. 33, 35.

---

Perhaps some of these require an understanding of various other catholic texts, but is there a list where I can find abbreviations and shorthands like these?

Comment: It seems you might mean Catholic with a capital C rather than the lowercase [catholic](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/catholic).

Comment: Well, it is an adjective. Doctrines pertaining to the Roman Catholic Church.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with theological texts but I suppose that these abbreviations have the same meanings as in scientific documents. As I have noticed in my readings, content-independent abbreviated words are mostly in Latin or English (or in another language depends on the context) in these type of texts. I am using [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Main_Page) to solve such puzzles. You can find a collection of [Latin abbreviated words or groups of words](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Latin_abbreviations) besides [English abbreviations](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_abbreviations). I am not sure about the *completeness* of these collections.

I suggest below description about your examples, you can check their meanings in English on respective links;

1. **f.** Council of Trent, session IV, **loc. cit.**: Denzinger 783 (1501).

   - ***f.*** *folio*, from Latin, **[link](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/f.)**
   - ***loc. cit.*** *loco citato*, from Latin, **[link](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/loc._cit.)**
2. **cf.** Second Council of Nicea: Denzinger 303 (602); Fourth Council of Constance, session X, Canon 1: Denzinger 336 (650-652).

   - ***cf.*** cōnfer, from Latin, **[link](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cf.)**
3. Cf. **Ibid.** 33, 35.

   - ***ibid.*** ibidem, from Latin, **[link](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ibid.)**

Comment: 'Cf' is short for 'confer' but means 'compare (the text referred to with the topic being discussed)'. 'Circa' is usually a small 'c' - I suggest 'C' may mean 'chapter'. A good dictionary should explain the main abbreviations, either in their alphabetical place or in a separate list.

Comment: "C" means *CAPUT" (Heading) in the given context: https://books.google.com/books?id=TfdPAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA5&dq=De+Catechizandis+Rudibus&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxkODkwaffAhVDqIsKHWPTAPU4ChDoAQhOMAc#v=onepage&q=De%20Catechizandis%20Rudibus&f=false